# Assign datetimeoffset string value to cookie , creating weird output in console javascript on front

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies

```
tokenExpirationTime //Datetimeoffset variable about expiration time of specific cookie
Response.Cookies.Append("cookie_name", tokenExpirationTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    Expires = tokenExpirationTime,
                    Domain = domain
                }
            );
```

When i read a cookie value at front i see such a output in the console.log: `22.04.2020%2004%3A42%3A42%20%2B02%3A00`

At backend it was: `22.04.2020 04:56:05 +02:00`

How read such a output in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let cookieExpirationTime = moment(
                           decodeURIComponent(
                           this.getCookieValue(
                           this.tokenValidToKey)))
                           .toDate();
```

decodeURIComponent was a missing piece